# Conversion from string to float changes the number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, floating-point

I have a string: 61146009 [sent from the server]

But when I print its float value

```
[string floatValue];
```

The output comes as 61146008.000000. I have tried sending the string as 61146009.0 too, but still the same result.

Any idea why?

The string needs to be displayed as 61,146,009 by using

```
NSString *formattedScore = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [scoreString floatValue]]];
```

It was a line of code written by somebody else who seems to have used float by mistake instead of int

I know using [string intValue] will fix it easily. But unfortunately the code is live with [string floatValue] and I am trying to fix the issue without having to release a new update.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try getting it as a Number first then get in as a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a double, not a float. Float has approximately 7 decimal digits of precison.

Comment: Got it. But is there a way I can change the payload being sent from the server to somehow get it to show correctly without having to modify the code on the client side?

Comment: If the client uses a float, any number with more than 23+1 bits of precision cannot be correctly handled by the client. Send a smaller number :P

Comment: These are high score getting displayed, if i send them as smaller numbers I think it'll make the players quite unhappy ;)

Comment: Cannot help much. The client will display either 61,146,009 or 61,146,012 (if I did the math right) but nothing in between. Try adding 3 to each score of this magnitude if you prefer to round "up", but there's not much more than you can do beside updating your client.

Comment: Yeah looks like I have no other option. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AnalogFile: The client displays 61,146,008, not 61,146,009. Binary floating-point never steps by three.

Comment: Yes. I meant ...08 or ...12, but I copy/pasted the number and forgot to edit it. The suggestion to add 3 is for rounding up. It will ensure ...08 stays ...08 but ...09 to ...12 all become ...12  
At that magnitude he's losing 2 bits of precision, not sure if by truncation or by rounding to closest, adding 3 means it will round up even if it happens by truncation.

Answer (score 3):

If the server sends the string “61146009”, then one of these is true:

1. The server has an IEEE 754 double-precision value, converted it to a string, and sent that.
2. The server has an IEEE 754 single-precision value, converted it to a string badly, and sent that.
3. The server has something other than an IEEE 754 double-precision or single-precision value.

The reason I list 2 is that 61146009 is not representable as an IEEE 754 single-precision value. As you have seen, the nearest representable value is 61146008. If the server has 61146008 and conversion to a string produced 61146009, then its formatting routine is bad and should be fixed or replaced. Your fix would be to change how the server converts the number to a string.

In the case of 1, the server has numbers that cannot be represented in a float (IEEE 754 single-precision object). This makes it impossible for the client to store them in a float. Since you do not want to change the client, you would have to change the server never to send values that cannot be represented in float. One way to do this is to modify the server to convert its value to single precision, then send it. The conversion will round the double-precision value to something representable in single precision.

The case of 3 is similar to 1: The server has numbers that cannot be represented in a float, and you would need to convert similarly.

Given what you have described, I do not expect there is any value you could send that would cause an unmodified client to display 61146009.

Comment: It is actually stored on the server as an integer and JSON sends it to the client as a string. Unfortunately the coder had written the code to handle the payload as a float. Stupid! thanks for your very nice explanation man. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This number is not representable in single precision float.
In hexa decimal, it is 0x3A50399, it thus needs 26 bits, two more bits than the 24 available in a Float mantissa.
So, you get the nearest Float number to your decimal input.

Comment: Oh! So how can I modify the string sent from the server to so that I do not need to modify the code?

Comment: @AbhinavVinay You can't undo the error at client side, once you converted to single precision float, it's too late, you losed information, and can't recover that simply. You can perform the same rounding error at server side if you want, but I doubt that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",string]
```

Comment: That displays as 61,146,008 too.
I want to make it work without having to change the code. Do you know how I can modify the string being sent from the server so that it is displayed correctly on the client?